# ajax loading modal before send and after complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
before send
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
complete send
```

This is my console out put from this ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        lname: lname,
        fname: fname
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)

    },
    error: function(data) {
        //console.log("error" + data);
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log('before send')
        $('#modal').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('complete send')
        $('#modal').hide();
    }
})
```

This is my modal div

```
<div id="modal"></div>
```

Style as

```
#modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                //url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 
                url('images/ajax-loader.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}

#modal {
    overflow: hidden;   
}
#modal {
    display: block;
}
```

But the problem is that my div modal is not showing. The console is ok. First `before send` will appear then the data is loaded then `complete send`

Comment: Please try to change the #modal background color to `background: #000;` just to make sure !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH i tried still same no modal is showing my new style is `#modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: #000 
                //url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 
                url('images/ajax-loader.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}`

Comment: No ! please try this : `#modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: #000;
}`

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH it was ok how can i apply the gif i tried this `#modal { display: none; 
         position: fixed; 
         z-index: 1000; 
         top: 0; 
         left: 0; 
         height: 100%; 
         width: 100%; 
         background: #fff 
                //url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 
                url('images/ajax-loader.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat; 
}` still no loading but the black screen is ok how to add the loading gid

Comment: Remove the commented url !

Comment: can you post this as answer so we can close the OP can you help me center the iamge though i used this `#modal { 
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1000; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    background: url('../images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat;

}` the url is now correct but the image is showing in lower left i want it in center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the commented `url` in your #modal CSS:

```
#modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 )  
                url('images/ajax-loader.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use show to display the modal

```
   $('#modal').show();
   $.ajax({...});
```

or in you case when ajax is triggered at page ready just display the modal as default using css

```
#modal {
    display:    block;
}
```

Comment: i have it in before send `beforeSend: function() {
        console.log('before send')
        $('#modal').show();
    }`

Comment: how do you trigger the ajax?

Comment: on page load.. it loads ok only problem is the modal is not showing

Comment: lol why are you hiding it in the first place if your ajax is at page load?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is happening so fast that you can't see it, use a timeout like below

```
complete: function() {
    console.log('complete send');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#modal').hide();
    }, 1000);
}
```

to see if there is a difference.

Comment: there is a bit long interval in `beforeSend: function() {
    },
    complete: function() {
    }` already.. So i dont think its the problem but i did try it same no modal appears